# Why is gconf-editor showing limited keys?

Tags: 14.04, automount, chromebook

Running 14.04 Trusty (on chromebook chroot) and trying to get rid of *volume mounting* desktop icons. As per many articles, trying to use `gconf-editor` to change `volumes_visible` key but there's nothing listed under the apps folder. Also tried using `dconf` and it shows a little more but only some apps I installed.

tried running `gksu gconf-editor` but same thing.
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My goal had been to remove the desktop icons for mountable volumes. I had not previously seen such an option under desktop settings. I think because i still had an older version of the xcfe desktop. After updating it to xfce 4.12 in xubuntu 14.04 and re-installing whisker as per NCODE 3/6/2015 - the desktop settings dialog showed a checkbox to not show the mountable volumes on the desktop.

I also first updated xubuntu and at this point I think I had an earlier version than 14.04. The conf-editor does show more entries now - specially under the gnome key - but the original question is now irrelevant - seeing that the conf editor is showing more stuff and I am able to remove the unwanted desktop icons without using that approach.